# Dynamically add a row if the coulmn count is more than 3 with using ng-repeat in angular js

Tags: html, css, angularjs, user-interface

I am doing dynamically create a table and rows with using angularjs (ng-repeate)

example html :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="obj in labellist">
            {{obj.label}}
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="obj in valauellist">
            {{obj.value}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Data:

```
$scope.labellist=[{lable:"Address1"},{lable:"Address2"},{lable:"Address3"},{lable:"Address3"},{lable:"Address5"},{lable:"Address6"}];

$scope.valauellist=[{Value:"AAA"},{Value:"BBBB"},{Value:"CCCC"},{lable:"Address1"},{Value:"DDDD"},{Value:"EEEE"}]
```

Now the result is displaying like

```
Address1        Address2       Address3      Address5      Address6     

AAAA             BBBB            CCCC         DDDDD           EEEEE
```

But I want to create `tr` tag if the `td` count is more than **3** *(n count of number)*  .

Like

```
 Address1        Address2       Address3      

 AAAA             BBBB            CCCC        

Address5      Address6     

 DDDDD           EEEEE
```

> I tried to solve this with using angular `$index % 2` formula. but it's not working for me **(any idea about this???).** So I decide to wrap the `td` tag like as `tr` tag while increasing (like responsive) the whole `td` size is greater than table width.

All ideas are appreciated ...

Comment: ng-repeat is angularjs...

Comment: by changing display property of td/tr this can be achieved

Comment: are you going to repeat those headings in each row of your table?

Comment: angular or angular 2 . I just need a solution with any kind of version. I have create a sample html with using angular 1. that's why I mentioned `angular.js` tag

Comment: @JayantPatil How can I do this? can you share any sample?

Comment: @Snorkpete . yes. but the all the array item size should be same. So we can achieve this with using $index . but I am blank .

Comment: Table is the wrong element of choice. What you looking for is a list. Tables are made for display table data. Why is your label data in a seperate object? Do you realy need a label object?

Comment: i agree with @lin - if you're repeating the heading, then i don't think a table is what you want.... and if you move away from using a table, you can use css to achieve your wrapping which is much easier to implement

Comment: @lin . Okay .  sure. But you have any idea about do this without using table element? or bring me a solutions with using any other kind of elements

Comment: I'll create a fiddle, hang on.

Comment: @Snorkpete . That's why I decide to go with css.  but I don't have much experience with css :(

Comment: @Lin thanks. Am waiting .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yezfzbm9/). It uses a `ul` list to achieve what you need. This solution does not base on 2 objects for rendering content and labels. I recommend to not store your labels and values in different objects.

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li class="column-3" ng-repeat="item in items">
      <strong>{{ item.header}}</strong><br/>
      {{ item.value }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{
      header: 'test',
      value: 'value 1',
    },{
      header: 'test',
      value: 'value 1',
    },{
      header: 'test',
      value: 'value 1',
    },{
      header: 'test',
      value: 'value 1',
    },{
      header: 'test',
      value: 'value 1',
    }];
});
```

#### CSS

```
.column-3 {
  width:33%;
  float:left;
}
```

Comment: Glad to help =)